# How to download more project templates for Expression Blend 4

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend

I want to create a WPF app with Blend 4 but only templates I have are for Windows Phone.
How to install additiional templates for WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install version for WPF - http://www.microsoft.com/expression/

Comment: I thought easy update would do it. So I will download whole Expression Studio 4.